# Selenium Grid Driver.Version Unknown

Tags: selenium, grid

I know that this question is asked many times and the answers helped me once.
I used to start as an experiment a Selenium Grid Hub on my local machine and an Node on an other machine. Both were started using parameters on the command line. I was able to start a test so the configuration worked.
Since I do not want to run the hub on my local machine I started is on the same machine as the node but now using JSON config files.
Now I get the `WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find ...` giving the driver.version: unknown error.
I am sure that I pass the version so the error leaves me puzzled.
The node is according to the hub's out put correctly registered. The nodeconfig JSON is:

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver",
      "version": 93,
      "platform": "WIN10" 
    }
    
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  "port": 5555,
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  "hub": "http://localhost:4444",
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

The console output in Eclipse shows this error description:

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=1920,955, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}, platform: WIN10, version: 93}
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'XXXXXXXXXX', ip: 'ipx.xxx.xxx.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_302'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

The hub show following:

```
ipy.yyy.yyy.yyy INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=1920,955, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}, platform: WIN10, version: 93}
ipy.yyy.yyy.yyy INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=1920,955, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}, platform: WIN10, version: 93}
org.openqa.grid.common.exception.CapabilityNotPresentOnTheGridException: cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=1920,955, --ignore-certificate-errors, --disable-gpu], extensions: []}, platform: WIN10, version: 93}
```

The Chrome version on the node is 93.0.4577.82. Do I need to spell this out?

Can anyone give me a clue how to solve this?

Comment: using parameters on the command line --> Can you share the commands?

Comment: And please share your `DesiredCapabilities` what you had in code.

Answer (score 0):

All examples on the net are showing version numbers like 93.0 or 93 .
So yes, I had to spell it out like 93.0.4577.82

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).